# Embedded Signing UI

Tags: docusignapi, hellosign-api

I am using the embedded UI for template and document creation. I want to know the data which are being filled in the UI and also have to store them in my DB and then hit to 3rd party tools for signing. Is this flow possible to store the data in my DB?

Answer (score 1):

With the HelloSign API, you have a few options to get information on the template:

The Get Template Endpoint
GET /template/[:template_id]
Gets general template details and includes a list of Accounts that can access it
https://app.hellosign.com/api/reference#get_template

The Get Template Files Endpoint
GET /template/files/[:template_id]
Obtains a copy of a template's original files.
https://app.hellosign.com/api/reference#get_template_files

And lastly, if you want the info that is being entered by the signer, you can poll the API or listen for callbacks that will supply you with said data to store in your DB.
https://app.hellosign.com/api/eventsAndCallbacksWalkthrough (best practice)

The Get Signature Request Endpoint can be used to poll this information
GET /signature_request/[:signature_request_id]
Gets a SignatureRequest that includes the current status for each signer.
https://app.hellosign.com/api/reference#get_signature_request